# Plotting (Graphing) a Quadratic Function with Vertex and Roots

Tags: plotting

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm not really familiar to the Mathematica functions and the language. Could any of you help me plot a quadratic with the following characteristics:

- vertex at (1.5, 1.75)
- roots at

[image]

('i' means the imaginary number 'i') How would I be able to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this what you want: `r1 = 15/10 + I Sqrt[7]/2;
p = Expand[(x - r1)*(x - Conjugate[r1])]
Plot[p, {x, -3, 3}]` which gives on V 10.01  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QD7yi.png) the poly is `4-3 x+x^2`

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, I think this is what I want, but how did you find this out? Is there a method to do this?

Comment: I added small description below

Answer (score 2):

You can use the definition that $p(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_i)$ where $r_n$ is the root.

```
root = 15/10 + I Sqrt[7]/2;  (*given*)
p = Expand[(x - root)*(x - Conjugate[root])]
Plot[p, {x, -3, 3}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"y(x)", None}, {x, p}}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
r = {1.5, Sqrt[7]/2};
p = {1.5, 1.75};
Plot[(x - r.{1, I}) (x - r.{1, -I}), {x, -3, 3}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@p}]
```

[image]